# Why are my GridView bit field columns blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an issue when displaying bit fields in a GridView, when the GridView is rendered the bit field is blank.

Code to bind to my GridView:

```
protected void InitGridViewDisplay(GridView mygrid, Button mybutton, DataTable mydt, int i)
{
    mygrid.DataSource = mydt;
    mygrid.DataBind();
    mygrid.Visible = true;
}
```

All other fields display correctly, but, the bit fields show as empty columns?

...after further discussion...

```
    for (int j = 0; j < mydt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        string fieldtype = Convert.ToString(mydt.Columns[j].DataType);
        if (fieldtype == "System.Boolean")
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in mydt.Rows)
            {
                string getrowvalue = Convert.ToString(row[j]);
                switch (getrowvalue)
                {
                    case "False":
                        {
                            row[j] = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "True":
                        {
                            row[j] = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

...Am I missing something? Columns is still blank when displayed in the GridView...

Comment: Cast the `bit` field as `boolean` and so that it will be displayed as `true` or `false`

Comment: The problem is the SQL for the GridView is different everytime...I take it I need to use an event to firstly detect the field type and then cast as needed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures in posts. Please see ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @bluenose1970 you can `loop` through `DataColumn` from `mydt` for checking `datatype` before binding it to `gridview`

Comment: Looping through the datacolumns, when accessing the field type, it's returning 'System.Boolean' already?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have a GridView with checkboxs. It checks and unchecks using a "Bit" value.

```
<Columns>
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox id="chkStatus" Enabled='<%# Enable(Eval("Status")) %>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

At code behind

```
 Protected Function Enable(ByVal sStatus As Boolean) As String
    If UCase(Trim(sStatus)) = True Then
        Return "true"
    ElseIf UCase(Trim(sStatus)) = False Then
        Return "false"
    End If
End Function
```

Arun